Windows Authentication not working over dev tunnel
In my asp net core backend I use Windows Authentication to secure some endpoints. In my Programm.cs I add the Authentication/Authorization like that:
builder.Services.AddAuthentication(NegotiateDefaults.AuthenticationScheme).AddNegotiate();

builder.Services.AddAuthorization(options =>
{
    options.AddPolicy("SoftwarePolicy", policy =>
    {
    policy.RequireRole(@"Mygroup");
    });
});


This works perfectly fine in the browser and it also works when using a private browsing tab (then a window opens and i first have to login to access the endpoint)
Now back to my problem:
I want to grant access to my backend for another developer, so I created a dev tunnel
I configured it like that:
Tunnel Type: Persistent
Access: Public
Now if I want to access the api using the dev tunnel a login window opens,then I login with the same information as I always do, but now it always says Unauthorized or forbidden
The access to endpoints without Authentication works fine.
I tried different Policies e. g. RequireUserName with my username but I still get no access

Is the other dev's machine joined to the same AD domain as your machine? Are you using the Fully Qualified username like someuser@yourdomain.com? Ideally Windows Authentication would use the already logged in user, not a specified username and password.

the other dev is in the same AD Domain as me and i tried the fully Qualified username.
You're right, i think its weird that it always opens the login window and doesn't use the logged in user (as it should later in production) i came to the conclusion that the dev tunnel has to do something with it but i'm not an expert

Sounds like perhaps you haven't got line-of-sight of the Domain Controller (or is this an AzureAD or Entra username?) or maybe you're not actually logged in to your machine with a domain user.

i am pretty sure that i am logged in with a domain user,  and i use authentication like here:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/authentication/windowsauth?view=aspnetcore-8.0&tabs=visual-studio

Hi Lukas, I have investigated the issue, and share the findings below, you also can check my test result in this thread.

@LukasSchneglberger it always opens the login window that's a matter of browser settings. If the browser isn't configured to log on automatically, or if the site isn't in the list of trusted sites, it will ask for credentials. In the Security page of the Internet Options control center applet, only sites in the Local Intranet and Trusted Sites will automatically login

Intranet penetration tools such as Devtunnel (or Ngrok) do not support windows authentication.
After checking the URL create by DevTunnel (such as https://23***k-7189.euw.devtunnels.ms/) by nslookup command, we will find that the IP 168.63.129.16 is used.
Then the application with Windows authentication enabled will always authenticate with 168.63.129.16 after penetrating the intranet, so it cannot be used.
